# JPM [info] Creating a new profile

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was developing Firefox Add on. I needed to switch language in Firefox browser. If i get it correctly, then the only way to do that is to reinstall entire browser. So, i did it, and now, when i'm trying to run Add on, i'm getting this:

```
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on AddonName addon
JPM [warning] Using existing install.rdf. This file is usually auto-generated.
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
```

... and that's all, nothing else happen: no errors, no messages - just this.
Well, it does open browser, but the add on is not there. Before firefox reinstallation, it was working absolutely fine.
What's wrong with this sdk?

OS X El Captain latest

I've tried to:
 - reinstall firefox again,
 - delete `install.rdf`,
 - reinstall `jpm`,
 - Run `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P`, create new profile and use it. Terminal output is different, but add on still not showing up in browser.

Neither makes any difference.

Comment: Holy heck,  does changing browser language seriously require a browser installation?

Comment: looks like so in firefox. If you will find another way - let me know)